Static and dynamic IP configuration with .network files using systemd
I can see 2 conf files(59-wlan0sta.network and 99-wlan0sta.network) related to wifi interface wlan0sta
here is the content of the files:
# cat /etc/systemd/network/59-wlan0sta.network

[Match] Name=wlan0sta [Network] Description=Use autoconfiguration for wlan0sta DHCP=no IPv6AcceptRA=no MulticastDNS=yes Address=192.168.188.90/24 Gateway=192.168.188.1 DNS= [DHCPv4] UseNTP=no UseDNS=yes [DHCPv6] UseNTP=no UseDNS=yes [IPv6AcceptRA] UseDNS=yes



# cat /etc/systemd/network/99-wlan0sta.network [Match] Name=wlan0sta [Network] Description=Use autoconfiguration for wlan0sta DHCP=yes IPv6AcceptRA=yes MulticastDNS=yes [DHCPv4] UseNTP=no UseDNS=yes [DHCPv6] UseNTP=no UseDNS=yes [IPv6AcceptRA] UseDNS=yes

I executed below DBUS command to apply my static IP changes, But I don't see it's applying changes but keeps ip address got it from DHCP config
# busctl call org.freedesktop.systemd1 /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/wpa_5fsupplicant_2eservice org.freedesktop.systemd1.Unit Restart "s" replace

Not sure how to apply static ip changes using "59-wlan0sta.network" config file changes.
Not sure how to use same file for both Static/DHCP IP configs How these 2 different files are created for same interface ? and WHY ?
Thank for the help
